# Arraylist replace the null value in java

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

my workflow
using mysql driver execute a query and saved the result set in arraylist, and from the arraylist fill the details in excel sheet (using Apache poi)

problem
if the arraylist contain null,during the insertion process in excel sheet getting null pointer exception.

my code

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (resultSet.next()){                    
    Date lastResponse = resultSet.getDate("lastresponse");
    response.add(lastResponse);                                         
    }
```

above arraylist contains the below values

```
2017-04-20, 2017-04-25, 2017-04-24, null, 2017-08-03
```

now i try to insert the above value(all) in excel sheet

```
for (int j = 0; j <= response.size(); j++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(j + 2);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(response.get(j).toString());            
        }
```

while run getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

expected solution

want to insert null value in the corresponding cell or need to replace the Hyphen symbol instead of null.

Comment: Why don't you just check `if(response.get(j)!=null)` before calling `response.get(j).toString()`? Or alternativly use `String.valueOf(response.get(j))` if you want to print "null" in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code needs is a null check. The null can be checked by the line

```
response.get(j)!=null
```

After this check you can change your code as you like.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= response.size(); j++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(j + 2);
                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                response.get(j)!=null ? cell.setCellValue(response.get(j).toString()) : cell.setCellValue("Null");

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`response = response.stream().map(x -> (x == null)? "-":x).collect()`